# Putting a talis on during Shabas mincha

Tags: shabbat, minhag, chazzan-prayer-leader, tallit-gadol, mincha-afternoon-prayer

Why (in some synagogues) does the *shatz* (leader) put on the *talis* during *mincha* of *Shabas*, before "*Vaani s'filasi*", rather than before the start of *mincha*?

As [Gershon Gold notes in his answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8464/putting-a-talis-on-during-mincha/8470#8470), *Shaare S'shuva* says this is because when we say "*Vaani s'filasi*" is a time of *ratzon*. And as I note in a comment to that answer, *Taame Haminhagim* says that it has to do with the words *vaani s'filasi*: a *talis* is connected to *t'fila*. But neither of them answers why we wait and put on the *talis* during *mincha* rather than before: after all, we don't *need* a *talis* until (let's say) "*Baruch sheamar*", yet we don it at the start of *shacharis*.

Comment: I've never seen such a thing.

Comment: me neither........

Comment: By the Chasidishe Shuls that is what they do.

Comment: A similar oddity (though I have no reason to think it's related): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36812

Comment: @msh210 Not everyone puts on the talis and tefillin at the start of shacharis - Minhag Ashkenaz is to put them on before Boruch She'omar

Answer (score 3):

[Shaarei Teshuva Orach Chaim Siman 292:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=138&hilite=), the Baal Tefila puts on the Tallis by Va'ani Sefilosi because it is an Eis Ratzon.

Comment: And _[Taame Haminhagim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=189&hilite=)_ says it's to do with the words "_vaani s'filasi_": because a _talis_ is connected to _t'fila_. But neither the _Shaa"S_ nor the _Taame Haminhagim_ explains why to don the _talis_ only right before it's 'needed'. I mean, we don't put on _talis_ and _t'filin_ right before "_Baruch Sheamar_" (since there are issues with saying the _b'racha_ afterward). We put them on before _shacharis_. If we're wearing the _talis_ for "_Vaani s'filasi_", why not put it on before _mincha_?