# When do you take off a Tallis which was put on for the Torah reading?

Tags: shabbat, torah-reading, tallit-gadol, mincha-afternoon-prayer

I have seen in many Ashkenazi synagogues that the person called to the reading of the Torah at Shabbos mincha puts on a tallis.

Typically, he takes this tallis off after the kedusho of the repetition of the Amidah.

I thought he wears the Tallis so as not to embarrass someone who is not dressed well when he goes up to read.

Therefore it would seem he could take it off immediately after the reading. Why is it worn after the Torah reading?

If it is to be worn for the Amidah, why is it not worn until the end in order not to disturb concentration in the repetition of the Amidah?

Comment: I disagree that the practice you describe is "typical".

Comment: In my shul, the person called to the torah at shabbos mincha does not wear a tallis.  Only the person reading the torah wears a tallis.

Comment: A similar oddity (though I have no reason to think it's related): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8464

Comment: At my shul, one who puts on a tallis for the aliyah removes it either after the aliyah or when he goes down from the bimah.

Comment: In typical Yekkishe shuls they keep the Tallis on until after Kedusha; other places tend to remove them immediately - usually to pass it to the next Aliya (which may explain why the Yekkishe Minhag vaporized). In Yeshivishe places they typically don't expect a Talis to be worn (possibly because everybody is in hat & Jacket, as per the embarrassment theory).